# How can I get the SlideIndex of a visible Slide in Powerpoint when SelectionType = ppSelectionNone

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have some code that requires me to know what `SlideIndex` to operate on (e.g., where to insert a new slide, where to insert a ChartObject, etc.).  About 99% of the time, I can successfully obtain the `SlideIndex` by:

```
Dim w as Long 'slide index variable
w = ActivePresentation.Windows(1).Selection.SlideRange(1).SlideIndex
```

The other 0.1% of the time, when `ActivePresentation.Windows(1).SelectionType = ppSelectionNone`, it will fail, because (understandably) it can't obtain the `SlideIndex` of the selection, because there is no selection. This might occur if the user has inadvertently "selected" the space between two slides in the Outline pane.

What I would like to do, ideally, is get the `SlideIndex` property of the slide which is visible in the Slides pane:

[image]
I currently have some code that tests whether the `SelectionType` is `ppSelectionNone`, so I can trap the condition, I just have not figured a way to identify the slideIndex of the Slides Pane.

```
Function GetMySlide()
Dim w as Long
    If Not ActivePresentation.Windows(1).Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then

        w = ActivePresentation.Windows(1).Selection.SlideRange(1).SlideIndex
        Set GetMySlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(w)

    Else:

        MsgBox "No slide is currently selected. Please select a slide in the Outline pane in order to proceed.", vbInformation
        Set GetMySlide = Nothing
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

**Update**

My interim solution is to use a public variable `lastUsedSlide` in an attempt to keep track of the most recently selected Slide.  I can incorporate this with the `WindowSelectionChange` event, but was hoping there would be a more straightforward solution.  If I thought this method would *always* work, I would use it, however, it potentially introduces unforeseen errors, since the `lastUsedSlide` is not a reliable proxy for `what_slide_i_am_currently_looking_at`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David, maybe you could use additionally `Activate` method for `Window.Pane` object like this:

```
'new code:
ActivePresentation.Windows(1).Panes(2).Activate
'your code
Dim w as Long 'slide index variable
w = ActivePresentation.Windows(1).Selection.SlideRange(1).SlideIndex
```

However, please read some more about `Pane.ViewType` property which could be helpful. In my simple test both `Panes(2)` and `Panes(3)` works but you could have different context of calling your sub.

Comment: I'll double-check, but when I tried that this morning, `Activate` was still leaving me with `SelectionType = ppSelectionNone`, and so therefore I was not able to refer to the `ActivePresentation.Windows(1).Selection.SlideRange...`.

Comment: OK, I think this might actually work. Let me test it a bit more :)

Comment: When in Normal view (PPT2016 btw), I can Activate Pane 2 (Slide) then Pane 1 (thumbnail) to force the thumbnail to be selected, but ONLY when stepping through the code. At run time, I end up without a selection!

Answer (score 4):

Potential workaround, here:

http://eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=1667

```
If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then
  Select Case ActiveWindow.ViewType
    Case ppViewNormal
      ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
      ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
    Case ppViewSlideSorter
      ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
      ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlideSorter
    Case Else
      ' ?
  End Select
End If
' A slide should be selected now
```

I don't particularly care for it, aesthetically, but it seems to work, kind of. Only thing is normallly if selection is between to slides, this forces selection to the first of those two slides, when I think the second would be more intuitive. I can modify my code to account for this, but it's still not ideal.

Comment: The second might or might not be more intuitive, but it's not how PPT works.  If you put the cursor between slides in sorter view or thumbnails pane then insert a new slide, it'll insert the new slide at the position of the cursor ... after the previous slide. That's possibly the logic behind how this behaves.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg good point. For my purposes, I think it is safe to assume that when a slide is in *view*, the user intends the application should act on this slide (not the preceding slide).  In any case, KazJaw's answer seems to do the trick by forcing the `Selection` back to the slide currently in view.