# PowerPoint: current slide in active presentation

Tags: view, powerpoint, slide

I'm looking at the best way to get the current slide in the active presentation.

The documentation says that when you are in a NormalView (ActiveWindow.View.Type = pptNormalView) you can access the current slide with ActiveWindow.View.Slide.

The problem with this approach is that when the user clicks on slides preview pane (left pane), and the focus goes between two slides (see the picture) the ActiveWindow.View.Slide cannot be reached, it throws a null pointer exception.

[image]

Is there a way to access the current slide in any case?

Thank you, F.

Comment: quite recently this topic was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652269/how-can-i-get-the-slideindex-of-a-visible-slide-in-powerpoint-when-selectiontype)

Comment: ummm... I'm going to test it. :)